# How to use Amazon EBS for persistent storage in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, dcos

We are working on setting up an ArangoDB cluster in DC/OS. For the data storage we've mounted 100 GB of
EBS to `/dcos/volume1` as mentioned and the disk space is getting reflected in the DC/OS dashboard.

However the ArangoDB Db server process gets launched with the below docker command :

> I0110 13:04:25.273998 21115 docker.cpp:815] Running docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock run --cpu-shares 1024 --memory 16106127360 -e CLUSTER_ROLE=primary -e CLUSTER_ID=DBServer005 -e ADDITIONAL_ARGS= -e AGENCY_ENDPOINTS=tcp://172.22.0.75:1025 tcp://172.22.0.198:1025 tcp://172.22.0.171:1025 -e HOST=172.22.0.128 -e PORT0=1025 -e LIBPROCESS_IP=172.22.0.128 -e MESOS_SANDBOX=/mnt/mesos/sandbox -e MESOS_CONTAINER_NAME=mesos-085398be-0bc9-4b23-9a13-4a7379530ea9-S3.1db76e46-20c1-48ba-ad2f-978874118930 -v /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/085398be-0bc9-4b23-9a13-4a7379530ea9-S3/frameworks/085398be-0bc9-4b23-9a13-4a7379530ea9-0045/executors/6f9b1b94-5dee-4454-bbe8-48f82e65d4d3/runs/1db76e46-20c1-48ba-ad2f-978874118930/myPersistentVolume:/var/lib/arangodb3:rw -v /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/085398be-0bc9-4b23-9a13-4a7379530ea9-S3/frameworks/085398be-0bc9-4b23-9a13-4a7379530ea9-0045/executors/6f9b1b94-5dee-4454-bbe8-48f82e65d4d3/runs/1db76e46-20c1-48ba-ad2f-978874118930:/mnt/mesos/sandbox --net bridge -p 1025:8529/tcp --name mesos-085398be-0bc9-4b23-9a13-4a7379530ea9-S3.1db76e46-20c1-48ba-ad2f-978874118930 arangodb/arangodb-mesos:3.1

Does this mean that the persistent data is stored within this location: `/var/lib/`? If so, is there any option to make the data get stored in different volume such as `/dcos/volume1`?

In the ArangoDB DCOS install config, I couldn't find any options to attach persistent volumes.